# misusage of the where in haskell

Tags: haskell, filter, boolean, list-comprehension

I am training in haskell and I would like to understand where I did go wrong.

The error is the infamous "variable not in scope"

The context is to determine if a sentence is a pangram. A pangram (Greek: παν γράμμα, pan gramma, "every letter") is a sentence using every letter of the alphabet at least once.

For example:

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

Here is the code:

```
module Pangram (isPangram) where

isFalse n = n == False

transformText :: String -> [Bool]

transformText text =  [letter elem alphabet | letter <-text] where alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

isPangram :: String -> Bool
isPangram [] = False
isPangram text = case test of
         Just _ -> False
         Nothing -> True
            where test = find isFalse (transformText text)
```

Comment: unrelated, but in `transformtext`, `letter elem alphabet` will give a compilation error. I assume you meant `letter \`elem\` alphabet` (which could also be written as `elem letter alphabet`, but the first is easier to understand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `where` should bind with the `case` part, so:

```
isPangram :: String -> Bool
isPangram [] = False
isPangram text = case test of
         Just _ -> False
         Nothing -> True
    where test = find isFalse (transformText text)
```

You can however simplify this. `isFalse` is equivalent to [**`not :: Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:not).

Your program also does not test if every letter is used, it checks if every item in the string is a letter.

You can replace the test with:

```
isPangram :: String -> Bool
isPangram text = all (`elem` text) ['a' .. 'z']
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, and the help. However, why do you say that my program does not test of every letter is used: if a item in the string belongs to alphabet, the true, else false which gives a list of boolean, and in this list I search for a false boolean, where do I go wrong ?

Comment: @Makoto: because that will check that for every `letter` it belongs to the alphabet. So that means that `"foo4bar"` will be rejected, since `4` is not an element of `alphabet`, but `"foo"` will be *accepted*, since all elements belong to the alphabet. You thus are testing the wrong predicate: you are testing if all letters belong to the alphabet, not that all elements in the alphabet are in the `text`.